# How to create another PWA from a PWA

Tags: javascript, android, html, ios, progressive-web-apps

I have a website where I want each page to have its own PWA icon (for both iOS and Android).

I'm able to dynamically change the manifest.json so the `name`, `icon` and `start_url` change depending on which page we are on, thus create a different PWA icon.

But the problem is after we launch one of these PWA:
The browser controls are not here anymore which also means no "Add To Home Screen" button.

So, **how can we create a PWA when already inside a PWA (in both iOS and Android) ?**

---

I focused on `the browser controls are not here anymore`, trying to have a link open the website outside of the PWA to get back the browser controls and the "Add To Home Screen".

But no matter what link I tried, with relative path, absolute path, with `window.open()`, or with a `target="_blank"` attribute, nothing worked.